# Did Chakotay ever take responsibility for Paris' safety?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

This is an extension to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23767/why-was-tom-paris-made-chief-helms-officer) question about Tom Paris becoming chief helms officer.

The question in question, had this quote in the answers:

> JANEWAY: Mr. Chakotay said something about his life belonging to you? He'll be taking responsibility for your safety.

Do we ever see Chakotay go out of his way to save Tom Paris? More so than he would for anyone else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, Chakotay didn't go out of his way to save Paris any more than any other of his friends or fellow crew members.

In context, the dialog is:

> Janeway: Mr. Paris, you have a problem. I've invited Chakotay and the other Maqui to become part of this crew. It seemed the only reasonable thing to do under the circumstances.
>
> Paris: Will you provide a bodyguard for me, Captain?
>
> Janeway: It seems you already have one.
>
> Paris: I do?
>
> Janeway: Mr. Chakotay said something about his life belonging to you? He'll be taking responsibility for your safety.
>
> Paris: I think I'm going to enjoy this.

Janeway is referring to Paris's quip that he needs a bodyguard due to his run-ins with the Maquis.

That is, it's implied by the dialog that Chakotay is repaying his debt to Paris by keeping the Maquis in line. It simply was a way to assuage the fear that the Maquis might do something nasty to Paris, because now he has Chakotay, the leader of the Maquis on board *Voyager*, to vouch for him.

Comment: I thought that Chakotay had a life debt to Paris in The Caretaker Part II.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris This question is specifically about a line taken out of context from [my answer here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/23768/366) which has nothing to do with Chakotay affirming any sort of oath to go out of his way to protect Paris. Yes, Chakotay owed his life to Paris, but he's not a Klingon and everyone aboard Voyager owed each other their lives at some point.

Comment: So I guess it hinges on the fact the Maquis never made an attempt on Paris? If they had, perhaps Chakotay may have stepped in then? Or am I misunderstanding the situation/your answer?

Comment: @Pureferret The Maquis left him alone, likely at Chakotay's urging. The first several episodes in season one go into how both Chakotay and Janeway integrated their respective crews into one unit, and there was no incident with Paris during this time.